# Structure and select data from a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, selector, cheerio

I am using cheeriojs to select elements from the pages on which I am developing the data collector however I have difficulties with this dynamic table,

This is an [environment](https://repl.it/@LuizFelipeNeves/ExampleHelp) with the [table](https://gist.github.com/LuizFelipeNeves/3de0c2e89b7fa86b6949381466632eec) code isolated from the full page.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

(async () => {
  const page = fs.readFileSync("table.html", "utf8");
  const $ = cheerio.load(page);
  const info = $("table tbody");

  info.each(function(i, element) {
    const text = $(this).html();
    console.log(text, "*----*");
    // console.dir(page, { depth: null });
  });
})();
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: I want to transform the tbody data to a json, but I only managed to get to the tbody list part and I don't know how to structure and select their information, because the table is dynamic.

Comment: Well, we don't know the structure of the table either. Without more information on what the input looks like and on how you want to output to look like, there is little anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

I made this example for you to improve.
It shows a print of the information inside the table.
Within a loop, iterating each TH and TD and returning the value

This script can be improved with refactoring.

Link online repl: https://repl.it/@lucasferreirali/ExampleHelp

```
const fs = require("fs");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

(async () => {
  const page = fs.readFileSync("table.html", "utf8");
  const $ = cheerio.load(page);
  const info = $("table tbody");

  info.each(function(i, element) {
    console.log("###################################\n")
    extractTR(this, i)
    console.log("___________________________________\n")
  });

  function extractTR(el, i) {
    let childrens = $(el).children()
    childrens.each(function(t, item){
      if(item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
        console.log(extractText(item, t))
      }
    });
  }

  function extractText(el, i) {
    let data = $(el).children(),
        text = [],
        type = [],
        result

    data.each(function(t, elm){
      text[t] = $(elm).text().trim()
      type[t] = $(elm).prop('tagName')
    });

    let [text_1, text_2] = text
    let [first, second] = type

    return result = first == "TD" && second == "TD" ? `${text_1}\n${text_2}` : `${text_1} ${text_2}`
  }
})();
```

Comment: The solution was merged with the project, thank you Lucas Ferreira.